# how can i change url in one word

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How Can i convert url ????
my current url

http://www.marketresearchandstatistics.com/report/ad/carbon-nanotubes-cnt-market-analysis-by-product-single-walled-carbon-nanotubes-swcnt-multi-walled-carbon-nanotubes-mwcnt-by-application-polymers-energy-electrical-electronics-and-segme/

and 
It's convert TO using htaccess

http://www.marketresearchandstatistics.com/report/carbon-nanotubes-cnt-market-analysis-by-product-single-walled-carbon-nanotubes-swcnt-multi-walled-carbon-nanotubes-mwcnt-by-application-polymers-energy-electrical-electronics-and-segme/

Comment: Do you mean "Removing a dir from the current url" ?

Comment: @starkeen yes  Remove current dir in "ad" word thanks

Answer (score 1):

To redirect `/report/dir/foobar` to `/report/foobar` , you can use the following redirect :

```
Redirect 301 /report/dir/ /report/
```

Comment: my current htaccess in change but show page redirecting eroor

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /report/ad/ /report/

# END WordPress

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: Try reordering you rule, put the redirect at top, and clear your browser cache before you restest it

Comment: Are there any other directives in your htaccess?

Comment: i remove that other thing in htacess but same problem are there